# using jquery to get datetime value in django form

Tags: jquery, django, datetime

In my django form I have a datetime input field which corresponds to a django.db.models.DateTimeField in models.py

```
my_date = django.db.models.DateTimeField
```

Currently , the form  shows an input field where I need to enter a value like

```
2012-09-30 08:50:46
```

I need to provide a javasrcipt popup to let user pick a datetime value..Which jquery component can I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a date and a time picker than I will suggest you to use

[jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).And if you want to add time also than use [Add time to jquery-datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

see also
[timepickr plugin](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

In webforms its not uncommon to split such inputs into two inputs, one for date and one for time. So keep in mind if you do a split like that there will be more options available.